# Get Common values in an single array

Tags: php

I want to get common values in an single array. Below I have shared my code for your reference

```
    $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

    $pack = array();        
    foreach($itemsVisible as $key => $item) {
       $productid = $item->getProductId();
       $select = "SELECT `pay4later_package` FROM `pay4later_payment` where `product_id`=".$productid;
       $query = $connection->fetchall($select);           
       $pack[] = array_column($query, 'pay4later_package');                                                      
    }
    $paypack = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $pack);
```

Output:

```
$paypack = {ONIF6: 6 Months Interest Free Credit (0%),ONIF6: 6 Months Interest Free Credit (0%),ONIF12: 12 Months Interest Free Credit (0%)}
```

Above output have two common values (i.e) `ONIF6: 6 Months Interest Free Credit (0%),ONIF6: 6 Months Interest Free Credit (0%)`.

How to get those two common values in an array?

Comment: What do you mean by get the common values? Do you want an array containing only the duplicated values?

Comment: @ Doug,Yes. correct

Comment: Can anyone please help me to get duplicate values in an array

Answer (score 0):

> You can get duplicate value from array please check bellow example code..
>    php array function array_unique and array_diff_assoc use for this

```
$main_arr = array('test','none','abc','test','none'); //here duplicate value 
$unique_arr = array_unique($main_arr);
$duplicate_record = array_diff_assoc($main_arr, $unique_arr);//get difference 
print_r($duplicate_record);
```

> check output like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => test
    [5] => none
)
```

Comment: It's not working because my array was looked like this array([0] => ONIF6: 6 Months Interest Free Credit (0%) [1] = > ONIF6: 6 Months Interest Free Credit (0%),ONIF12: 12 Months Interest Free Credit (0%)). so, array_unique returns same value

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_count_values()` and `array_filter()` with filtering callbacks.

```
$multiple = array_filter(
    array_count_values($paypack),
    function ($count) { return $count > 1; }
);

$paypack = array_filter(
    $paypack,
    function ($value) use ($multiple) { return isset($multiple[$value]); }
);
```